# Access cell in table and click

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am writing a script to automate certain tasks. I am at a point where I have a table and hyperlinked name written in its second row, first column ([2][1]). I want to access that cell and click on it to go to intended page. Structure of the page looks like this:

```
<table id="listViewTable" class="listview" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">

<tbody></tbody>
<tbody id="lvTred">
    <tr id="1381137000000078119" class="tdout">
        <td width="10" data-cid="dummy"></td>
        <td class="lvCB" data-cid="dummy"></td>
        <td>
            <a id="listView_1381137000000078119" class="link" href="/crm/EntityInfo.do?id=1381137000000078119&module=Potentials&relCntId=1381137000000078117" data-params="{"relContactId":"1381137000000078117","module":"Potentials",…id":"1381137000000075541","recordNum":"1","lookback":"true"}" data-cid="detailView"></a>
        </td>
```

I have successfully accessed table with id 'listviewTable' but not able to access cell with id 'listView_1381137000000078119' which is at location [2][1] in table. I did something like this:

```
cell = table.cell(:id, 'listView_1381137000000078119')
```

where table is actual table with mentioned id. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML, there is no `<td>` tag with an `id` attribute of  `listView_1381137000000078119`.  However, there is an `<a>` tag with an `id` attribute of  `listView_1381137000000078119`.

```
puts b.table.td(:id, 'listView_1381137000000078119').exists?   
puts b.table.link(:id, 'listView_1381137000000078119').exists?
#=> false
#=> true
```

Comment: puts b.table.td(:id, 'listView_1381137000000078119').exists? is giving me false. But it gave me true with link!

Comment: Sorry.  Had it backwards.  Should have just cut/pasted.  Edited now.